# Python Beautiful Soup surfing through tag attributes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: code for web scraping]

How can I get all id names using BS find or find_all?

I tried:

```
all = PS.find(class_='store-collection')
All_id = all.find_all('id')
for all_id in All_id:
   name_id = all_id.get_text()
```

I want to have all id to then make operations on 'store-collection__items store-collection__items--desktop'

Comment: `find` or `find_all` are not for this purpose. You cannot get all id names with it. You need to use a regex to get all ids

Comment: @MoosaSaadat How can I do this by regex? After I get id I want to find some attributes of store-collection__items store-collection__items--desktop'

Comment: @wtfvba you've to [edit] your question and post the `HTML` part as a code instead of pic

Answer (score -1):

Surf it through like you do in dictionary:

```
all = PS.find("section",class_='store-collection')
ids = []
for i in all.findall('div'):
    ids.append(i['id'])
```

Here, `i` is of the form:

```
<div id = 'blah blah' ....></div>
```

so, `i['id']` gives:

```
blah blah
```

Note:

- If its the data in classes that you require, use `id['class']`
- This works only if `PS` has a `<section class = 'store-collection' ...>`

Comment: Still doesn't work - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findall'

Comment: PS is page source

Comment: @wtfvba pls include the content inside PS in your question. Like i said you get the error because the thing you are trying to scrap doesnt exist